# c# : How to get response and parse it for below Rest Assured

Tags: c#, rest, api, rest-assured

What below code returns depending on that how to get that response and parse it

How to verify status code, content, url,type etc from response

```
new RestAssured()
                    .Given()
                        .Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .Header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                        .Host("http://qa.services.theknot.com")
                        .Uri("/local-partners/marketplace/v1/storefronts")
                        .Query("apikey", "ca7f6e91ee8134de9717707d86b29100")
                        .Body("{ 'Id': [323920, '3a6b4e0b-8e5c-df11-849b-0014c258f21e'] }")
                    .When()
                    .Post()
                    .Then()
                        .Debug();
```

Comment: Add your assertions in `Then()` like `Then().statusCode(200)`

Comment: There is no direct method after Then to verify Status code in C#. Is purpose of test status is same? And how can i verify different response content attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use `.TestBody("string", Func<dynamic, bool>)` or `TestStatus("string", Func<int, bool>)` or refer to [documentation](https://github.com/lamchakchan/RestAssured.Net/blob/master/README.md) .

Answer (score 0):

```
new RestAssured()
.Given()
  .Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .Header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
  .Host("http://qa.services.theknot.com")
  .Uri("/local-partners/marketplace/v1/storefronts")
  .Query("apikey", "ca7f6e91ee8134de9717707d86b29100")
  .Body("{ 'Id': [323920, '3a6b4e0b-8e5c-df11-849b-0014c258f21e'] }")
.When()
  .Post()
.Then()
  //Here you make your tests on body, status.
  // Utilize method AssertAll() to verify all tests performed
  //Where "y.result.msg" is extract from json, use http://jsonpath.com to do.
  .Debug()
  .TestStatus("codResponse", x => x == 200)
  .TestBody("msg", y => y.result.msg == "Your response message")
  .AssertAll();
```

Comment: Here you use methods for validade de reaponse and .assertAll() to validate ALL tests of response.